# Converting Object[] to string in Apache Logger

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I have an object array from a Hibernate query that I want to show in a `logger` message.

I have

```
//row output
for (Object[] objs : results) 
{
    logger.info(objs.toString());
}
```

but I get `[Ljava.lang.Object;@60cf75a9` for each.

How do I convert the array to a string output?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the `.toString()` method of `Object[]`.  Use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-)

```
for (Object[] objs : results) 
{
    logger.info( Arrays.toString( objs ) );
}
```

Comment: That's it thanks. I tried Arrays.toString before and got syntax errors, think i used it with a String.format(). Your example works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to over-ride the toString method to suit your needs. Right now it's printing out the memory address of each object in the array.

```
public String toString() {
//              Return whatever aspect of the object you want to display.
}
```